# Command to get the disk usage by a user in a directory in linux

Tags: linux, memory

I would like to get the memory used by a particular user, for eg: abcd,in a particular location (/location/here/).
I tried 
"find -user abcd | du -sh /location/here/
"
But it is not working.

Could you please help?

Thanks,
Anila

Comment: Welcome. You might get more help on forums like [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Stack Overflow is about programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, result is in bytes.

```
find /location/here -user abcd-exec du -b {} \; 2>/dev/null | awk 'BEGIN {a=0} {a=a+$1} END {print a}'
```

Cheers

Comment: Note that this will account for folders, each folder will weight 4K, so take that into account. If you don't want that, just add the -type f in the find command.